# Change Android's activity on background

Tags: android, android-activity, android-background

I have a app that uses webscockets, and when the app goes to backgroud i need after a x amount of seconds to disconnect the websckets and change the current activity to the lobby activity.

I have a singleton that extends Application and implements
ActivityLifecycleCallbacks, each activity is registered on registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks.

The problem is that when the app is in background and i call the lobby activity, the new activity calls all Activity Lifecycle Callbacks, like onActivityCreated, onActivityStarted, onActivityResumed and then onActivityStoped, and that behavior forces my to do a bunch of checks to see if the lobby activity is called on background or on foreground.

Is there a way to do this without that behavior, like to put the activity on hold ready to start on app resume?

And i prefer not to call the new activity when the app resumes it feels jerky, because you see the last open activity and then you see the change to the lobby activity.

Sorry for the long question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a **Service** to achieve that you want

Visit http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but  i cant see how services could help me in this case.